# convert JSON data inside a new columns

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

i have dataframe like this:

```
id    date         value   
1     2021-09-01   [{'value': 'Keyman', 'sum': 8932.199999999999}
                   {'value': 'Suluboya', 'sum': 5896.7499999999945}]

2     2021-10-01   [{'value': 'Atelier', 'sum': 5595.299999999992}
                   {'value': 'Atölye4D', 'sum': 3538.7299999999987}]
```

expected output:

```
idx    date        value       sum
1     2021-09-01   Keyman      8932.199999999999 
2     2021-09-01   Suluboya    5896.7499999999945            
3     2021-10-01   Atelier     5595.299999999992
4     2021-10-01   Atölye4D    3538.7299999999987
```

i tried:

```
df = pd.json_normalize(df['value'][0])
```

this was for the first row only. It works but there is a lot of data than that and I believe there is a shorter way. I tried this too.

```
def only_dict(d):

    return ast.literal_eval(d) if pd.notnull(d) else {}

dfy = json_normalize(df['value'].apply(only_dict).tolist()).add_prefix('_')
```

but i am getting this error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: The easy to do but the long way would be to use your own way, but in a loop, ie, `df = pd.json_normalize(df['value'][0])` where `0` would be `i`

Comment: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/4046632)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your df to be:

```
In [577]: df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2], 'date':['2021-09-01', '2021-10-01'], 'value':[[{'value': 'Keyman', 'sum': 8932.199999999999},{'value': 'Suluboya', 'sum': 5896.7499999999945}], [{'value': 'Atelier', 'sum': 5595.299
     ...: 999999992},{'value': 'Atölye4D', 'sum': 3538.7299999999987}]]})

In [578]: df
Out[578]: 
   id        date                                              value
0   1  2021-09-01  [{'value': 'Keyman', 'sum': 8932.199999999999}...
1   2  2021-10-01  [{'value': 'Atelier', 'sum': 5595.299999999992...
```

You can use `df.explode` with `df.apply`:

```
In [581]: df1 = df.explode('value')

In [585]: df1 = pd.concat([df1['date'], df1.value.apply(pd.Series)], 1)

In [586]: df1
Out[586]: 
         date     value      sum
0  2021-09-01    Keyman  8932.20
0  2021-09-01  Suluboya  5896.75
1  2021-10-01   Atelier  5595.30
1  2021-10-01  Atölye4D  3538.73
```

**OR** use `pd.json_normalize`:

```
In [587]: df1 = df.explode('value')
In [597]: df1 = pd.concat([df1['date'].reset_index(drop=True), pd.json_normalize(df1['value'])], 1)

In [598]: df1
Out[598]: 
         date     value      sum
0  2021-09-01    Keyman  8932.20
1  2021-09-01  Suluboya  5896.75
2  2021-10-01   Atelier  5595.30
3  2021-10-01  Atölye4D  3538.73
```